# Laptop HDMI out to monitor DVI in

Tags: hdmi, cable, dvi

I have a laptop that i'm trying to fix, and it has HDMI out.  I have a cable i bought for my HTPC which does DVI out to HDMI in, which worked fine.   Was hoping to be able to use this same cable for HDMI out to DVI in, is it possible?

UPDATE: Point of clarification, The laptop's display doesn't work (it was dropped) and I'm trying to figure out what's working and what isn't.  in addition to HDMI out, it has VGA out, but that seems to have a short in it, and doesn't display properly (sometimes it works, sometimes, it shows stuff in 256 colors in 800x640).    I can tell the LCD screen works (comes on) so i think it's whatever is carrying the data to it that doesn't work.  I know more often than not, it's usually the display that breaks...

The cable i'm using is a standard HDMI to DVI cable, there are no audio connections or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you are just talking about a dvi to hdmi cable.  Hook it up and find out. :) Obviously, if you are doing HDMI out and DVI, you will not have audio, just video.

If you had some links to exactly the kind of cables and setup you are doing, that would help us help you better.

EDIT:

Hmm, maybe that cable only works one way.  DVI out to HDMI in.  If the VGA out is having trouble, there is a good chance the other connections might have issues as well.  Is the VGA at least usable to see what works and not, beyond the color issues?

Comment: Thanks.  I've already hooked it up and it didn't work, so i just wanted to see if I was doing something that's not possible or if i had a HDMI port that didn't work. (updated original question with more info)

Comment: I'd first make sure you're connecting the HDMI correctly by connecting to a TV, where you don't need the conversion.